# Using replace and concat in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have strings values such as the following in a column:

```
|333|,|331|
```

I want to perform a balanced string replacement as follows:

```
xxTM_333_TMxx,xxTM_331_TMxx
```

I have tried to do this with the `REPLACE` and `CONCAT` functions but didn't get the desired output.

For example:

```
SELECT REPLACE('|333|,|331|','|','xxTM');
```

This replaces one of the `|` symbols correctly in each case, but not its matched (balanced) counterpart.

How can I achieve this result in MySQL?

Comment: What did you try exactly? What output did it give?

Comment: select replace('|333|,|331|','|','xxTM');

Comment: You can't do this with built-in functions in MySQL. The problem is that `|` means something different for every alternative match. You can do this with a regular expression replace, which MySQL doesn't support natively. Do it in your application.

Comment: `select concat(trim(TRAILING 'xxTM' FROM replace(replace('|333|,|331|,|234|','|','xxTM'),'xxTM,xxTM','TMxx,xxTM')),'TMxx');` will output `xxTM333TMxx,xxTM331TMxx,xxTM234TMxx `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @st := '|333|,|331|';

SELECT
  CASE WHEN @st LIKE '|%|' THEN
    CONCAT(
      'xxTM',
      REPLACE(REPLACE(@st, '|,|', '_TMxx,xxTM_'), '|', '_'),
      'TMxx')
  END rep_st;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/20008).